# EPPlus returns {#NAME?} when trying to get the value from a Cell which contains the FILTER function

Tags: c#, epplus

I have an Excel file with several sheets. One of these sheets contains a cell with the following formula:

```
=FILTER(AnotherSheet!F:F,AnotherSheet!$A:$A="ABCD",99)
```

When I open this file on Excel the value of this cell gets properly evaluated, but when I try getting this value on code, the value I get is {#NAME?} instead. This is the code I am using

```
using var fs = new FileStream(@"{path_to_my_file}", FileMode.Open);
using var package = new ExcelPackage(fs);

var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Single(w => w.Name == "MainSheet");
var x = ws.Cells["Y9"].Value // this yields {#NAME?}
```

The formula returned by `ws.Cells["Y9"].Formula` is apparently correct as well:

```
"_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(AnotherSheet!F:F,AnotherSheet!$A:$A=\"ABCD\",99)"
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this not supported by EPPlus for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a formula like that to EPPlus. You need to add proper `Address`. See my full demo below. It adds 3 sheets, 2 of which have values. Then on the first sheet a formula is added that references a different sheet. I use `SUM` and `COUNT`, so you have to change it to `RANGE` (not familiar with it).

```
//create a new ExcelPackage
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
    //create the WorkSheet
    ExcelWorksheet ws1 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
    ExcelWorksheet ws2 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 2");
    ExcelWorksheet ws3 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 3");

    //add some dummy data, note that row and column indexes start at 1
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        ws2.Cells[i, 1].Value = rnd.Next(1, 25);
        ws2.Cells[i, 2].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        ws2.Cells[i, 3].Value = "Value " + rnd.Next(1, 25);
        ws2.Cells[i, 4].Value = rnd.Next(1, 25);

        ws3.Cells[i, 1].Value = rnd.Next(1, 25);
        ws3.Cells[i, 2].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        ws3.Cells[i, 3].Value = "Value " + rnd.Next(1, 25);
        ws3.Cells[i, 4].Value = rnd.Next(1, 25);
    }

    //add some formulas to sheet 1
    ws1.Cells[1, 1].Formula = string.Format("SUM('{0}'!{1}:{2})", ws2.Name, ws2.Cells[1, 1].Address, ws2.Cells[ws2.Dimension.End.Row, 1].Address);

    ws1.Cells[1, 2].Formula = string.Format("COUNT('{0}'!{1}:{2})", ws3.Name, ws3.Cells[1, 4].Address, ws3.Cells[ws3.Dimension.End.Row, 4].Address);

    //calculate the formulas
    ws1.Calculate();

    //convert the excel package to a byte array
    byte[] bin = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
}
```